# How to geocode to zip code centroid?

Tags: geocoding

I created centroids for zip codes and now want to geocode a table of addresses to the zip code centroid. I created an address locator and chose zip code as type. However I am unable to geocode to the zip code centroid. The table of addresses consist of city, state, and zip.

Comment: That sounds like a simple table join using the zip code as the common field.

Comment: Yes, if you have ZIP code centroids and data with a ZIP code attribute; join them. You do not need to geocode anything, in a sense you have already done that. What is the application?